# Number of passed/failed parameterized junit test method executions

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

I have a junit5 test class with several parameterized (integration) tests. Most tests use a `MethodSource` which can produce a different amount of Arguments depending on external factors.

When I run the tests, I get only the total amount of tests executed in the whole run, both in the junit IDE integration and in the surefire reports. But what I need are these numbers on a per-method basis. I.e. instead of

```
Tests failed: 808, passed: 2366
```

I need something like this:

```
Test_1 failed: 200, passed: 1000
Test_1 failed: 100, passed: 1000
Test_1 failed: 508, passed: 366
```

Is there any tool that can do this out of the box? I could parse the surefire reports to extract this information, but I guess I don't want to believe this is the best solution.

I understand that I could have several test runs, each executing only one of the test methods. I don't want to do this, though, as during one test execution communication with external components is cached, and I can't afford to lose this benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One flexible approach is creating a custom test listener or extension in JUnit 5 that collects and logs statistics for each test method.

Simple example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterTestExecutionCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class PerMethodStatisticsExtension implements AfterAllCallback, AfterTestExecutionCallback {
    private final Map<String, Integer> passedCount = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Integer> failedCount= new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) {
        final String testMethodName = context.getTestMethod().get().getName();
        if (context.getExecutionException().isPresent()) {
            failedCount.merge(testMethodName, 1, Integer::sum);
        } else {
            passedCount.merge(testMethodName, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterAll(final ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        log.info("Passed test statistics: " + passedCount);
        log.info("Failed test statistics: " + failedCount);
    }
}
```

You can then register this extension in your test classes like this:

```
@ExtendWith(PerMethodStatisticsExtension.class)
public class YourTest {
    @Test
    void testMethod1() {
        // Your test logic
    }

    @Test
    void testMethod2() {
        // Your test logic
    }
}
```

If that is not helpful, please consider providing more information with some test classes.

Good Luck!

Comment: It looks like junit treats every execution of a parameterized test method as its own test execution, therefore this solution sadly doesn't work. It logs after every test execution, the count is always 1/0 or 0/1. But I liked this approach and made it work with slight modifications, using AfterAllCallback, AfterTestExecutionCallback and two Maps with the test method name as key and passed/failed counter as value. I can't propose an edit to your answer right now because of SO problems, I'll try later.

Comment: Glad that you worked it out :) I like your modified version, as it provides a higher level of granularity in cases like yours where you have parameterized tests with varying numbers of arguments.